# Default radio button selected but it is not working for image

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I have created a default radio button but it is not loading image on page.
Here is my radio button.

```
 <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="level" value="B1" checked<?
   php if (isset($_POST[ 'level']) && $_POST[ 'level']=='B1' )?>onclick="this.form.submit()">Basement 1</label>
                </div>
```

When I'm loading the page it is clicking on Basement1 as default value but not loading image.

And here is my code for image loading:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <img src="image/<?php echo $val1 ?>" alt=<?php echo $level ?> width="100%" height="100%">
    </img>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `$val1`?

Comment: check val1 if getting src then check path from inspect or right click and make sure image is there in path

Comment: Error no your alt value for image . Probably it will be alt="<?php echo $level ?> "

Comment: edit your question with html page source view .

Comment: where is the end of `if` ??

Comment: Your question is very uncleared .

Comment: Thanks Ahmed I know now where i am doing wrong.